# Magento 2.4 Admin Page Two Factor Authentication

Tags: magento2, two-factor-authentication

I'm trying to install Magento 2.4 Version on my Local System and getting a Two Factor Authentication option when I log in with admin page credentials.

**Steps Taken by me to solve this issue -**
I try to bypass this Admin page Authentication Step by following this link, But not find the required information to solve the same. - [Officals Docs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/security/two-factor-authentication.html)

[image: Two Factor Login Option at Admin Page]

Comment: please verify if you are able to send mails with php. I suggest to use mailhog or any other mailcatcher for local development.

Comment: Pratik Oza's answer helped me to resolve the problem, I used option 2 as a quick workaround. Maybe you could accept his answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 7):

**Option 1:**

Please configure SMTP in your local system to send/receive email notification and after setup 2FA.

[SMTP Extension for Magento 2](https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-smtp)

**Option 2:**

Temporary workaround to setup 2FA without having SMTP:

1. navigate to /admin and log in
2. you should see the 2FA screen now
3. add `var_dump($url);die;` on line 86 (*function sendConfigRequired*) in `vendor/magento/module-two-factor-auth/Model/EmailUserNotifier.php`
4. refresh /admin
5. copy the URL that is displayed
6. remove the var_dump
7. use the URL copied earlier to navigate to the 2FA setup

**Option 3:**

Temporary disable TwoFactorAuth module using following command(for dev environment):

```
php bin/magento module:disable Magento_TwoFactorAuth
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

**Option 4:**

Install the following module to enable/disable two-factor authentication from backend:

[DisableTwoFactorAuth](https://github.com/markshust/magento2-module-disabletwofactorauth)

Answer (score 0):

For quick access, I recommend disabling the Magento TwoFactorAuth

```
bin/magento module:disable Magento_TwoFactorAuth
```